# THREE.js CanvasRenderer with the OrthographicCamera

Tags: three.js

I'm just beginning to experiment with THREE.js. I'm trying different combinations of renderers and cameras.

I can render a simple animation using the WebGLRenderer and the OrthographicCamera or the CanvasRenderer and the PerspectiveCamera. But if I use the CanvasRenderer with the OrthographicCamera I don't see any image rendered.

Should the CanvasRenderer work with the OrthographicCamera? Fiddles that work are here:

http://jsfiddle.net/PXxLq/ - WebGL/Orthographic - OK

http://jsfiddle.net/fXsKq/ - Canvas/Perspective - OK

This is the code that fails:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>

SCREEN_WIDTH = 200;
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 200;

var ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 1, FAR = 1000;

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
// PerspectiveCamera good with CanvasRenderer
//var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( -SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2,   SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, -SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, NEAR, FAR );

var renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
// WebGLRenderer good with OrthographicCamera
//var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(50,50,50);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x000000, wireframe: true });
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(cube);
camera.position.z = 100;

function render() { 
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
} 

render();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `CanvasRenderer`, when using `OrthographicCamera`, the `near` plane must be negative.

This appears to be a bug.

EDIT: This bug has been fixed. The near plane should always be positive now.

three.js r.55

Comment: Wow! Making near negative fixed my problem! I'd call that behavior a bug too. Have you reported your discovery to the THREE.js developers?

Comment: Reported as a bug - Issue #2890

Comment: Fixed by WestLangley. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Reference : WebGLRenderer() & PerspectiveCamera()
- List item

  ```
  <script src="build/three.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      var scene = new THREE.Scene();
      var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera
      ( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

      var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
      document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

      var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
      var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
      var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
      scene.add( cube );

      camera.position.z = 5;

      var render = function () {
          requestAnimationFrame( render );

          cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
          cube.rotation.y += 0.1;

          renderer.render(scene, camera);
      };

      render();
  </script>
  ```